# Get SQL Column Names & Values

Tags: c#, sql, parsing

I wanted to ask how can I extract the column names & their respective values from SQL query without executing the statment.

For Example:

```
select * from table where fieldname = 'fieldvalue'
```

I want to extract "FieldName" and "FieldValue" from the query.

```
Insert into table (field,field2,field3) 
values ('fieldvalue','field2avlue','field3'svalue')
```

I want to extract "field","field2" and "fieldvalue","field2avlue","field3'svalue" from the query.

Comment: What do you mean for 'extract'?. Parsing the text and finding the column names and column values for every possible kind of sql text?

Comment: @Steve Yes, thats right.

Comment: That will be an huge task. You need some parsing library but I don't know if exists something DBMS independent. Can you explain why do you need this functionality? Perhaps there is another way.

Comment: @Steve What I need to do is put an extra '(single quote) in the values of the field because if the field name contains '(single quote) like Smith's Mother they will not be saved in the database because SQL format, so I thought Instead of putting an axtra '(single quote) in each field's value of every table I would just parse the Query put an extra '(single quote)

Comment: Then the ideal way to address that issue would be to clean up the field values before they are included in the SQL query.  As pointed out in @Lluluien's answer, you will need the table's metadata to perform this properly after the SQL query has already been built.

Comment: If these are strings to be submitted to the database engine for processing then the right (and ONLY) way to have _clear_ values is through the parameters object added to a command object. I think that if you edit your question adding the code around the commands to update the database we can offer a different solution

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using @Sandra Walters suggestion i.e: The ideal way to address that issue would be to clean up the field values before they are included in the SQL query, you will need the table's metadata to perform this properly after the SQL query has already been built.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your answer to Steve, you're talking about parsing it yourself?  You can't do that just based on code if you have anything that is resolved by looking at table metadata like the "*" in "select *" you have above.  You'd have to have the table metadata too.  If you're really talking about doing what you've said here, you're talking about recreating a major component of the DBMS itself.  Like Steve said - that's a huge task.

If you're not trying to write your own SQL parser and you really do have access to a database in an application, this is actually pretty easy.  It's not an unreasonable problem to come up either - there could be real applications where you need the result set metadata without running some query that could have potentially enormous execution time, or some other similar restriction.

To get the metadata without getting any significant execution time, putting any locks on the involved tables, etc., etc., put a predicate in your where clause made out of literal values that are guaranteed to fail.  All modern DBMS are smart enough to optimize this to give you no rows returned, but most APIs for retrieving results still capture the result set metadata anyway.  You will be executing your query, but the query will run fast, lock nothing, and give you the result metadata.

Example:

```
select 
    <lots of stuff>
from
    <complicated subquery>
where 
    <there are a ton of predicates>
    AND 0=1
```

That last line is what guarantees no results.